# Getting OSStatus error 100021 when trying to ad hoc distribute ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, adhoc

[image: OSStatus error 100021]

Im getting this awful and weird error when having selected an ad hoc distribution certificiate in Xcode in the Distribute for Ad Hoc section. Anyone know how to fix this error? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just fixed the same error in my project. I'll explain the fix, and I'd love to know if it helps.

I had just added the [YAJL library](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc#readme) to my iOS project. The problem was that I had followed the Mac OS X instructions, rather than the iOS. The Mac OS X instructions include the creation of a Copy Files Build Phase, that copies the YAJL.framework/ folder to the .app bundle.

> This is a huge mistake.
>   [image]

Now, what does a framework folder look like inside? It looks like this:

[image]

See those symbolic links? (The files with the curvy arrows) They are the culprits. Delete all of those out of the .app folder, and I was able to save the .ipa file with no trouble at all. Actually, you don't need the .framework/ folder in the app bundle at all. That should be compiled into the binary.

So, check your .app file. Are there any weird folders that don't need to be there? Are there any symbolic links hanging around?

Comment: That was what I figured aswell! Thanks!

Comment: Not at all, glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in the Mac world. It turns out that removing the symbolic links is only tricking the archive tool, and it doesn't really produce a valid result. This error usually happens if one of your embedded frameworks has a bad Info.plist file.

But yes, in an iOS app you can't have embedded frameworks so you should be linking against a static library.